# JSON: Python Output File to Java ObjectMapper - Wrong Sizes

Tags: java, python, json, jackson

So, I'm taking data from NLTK in Python and printing it to a file (with JSON) so I can load it into Java. This is what I'm doing in Python.

```
wordcounts = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((w.lower(), t) for w, t in brown.tagged_words())
print wordcounts.N()
with open('test.json', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(wordcounts, outfile)
```

Then, in Java, I load the json file. I'm using Jackson. The code is:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
 Map<String,Object> word = mapper.readValue(new File("test.json"), Map.class);
 System.out.println(word.size());
```

It all seems to work, however, the output of (Java) word.size() is not even close to the size of python's wordcounts.N(). The size of the Python output is 1161192 and the Java size is only 49815.

Does anyone have any idea what went wrong?

**EDIT:**
More Information as requested:

A snip of the output file from python that I'm loading looks like this

```
"dronk": {
    "NP": 2
}, 
"dronk's": {
    "NP$": 1
}, 
"droop": {
    "VB": 1
}, 
"drooped": {
    "VBD": 1
}, 
"drooping": {
    "VBG": 1
}, 
"drop": {
    "JJ": 1, 
    "NN": 24, 
    "VB": 34
},
```

Clarification.

```
System.out.println(word.size());
```

Prints out

```
56057
```

And

```
 print wordcounts.N()
```

Prints out

> `1161192`

1161192 is the correct size.

Comment: Show us a part of the json and expected value to this part

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... The python output size and the Java size should be the same

Comment: I wanna see a part of the json to test, example: `{ 'word': 'abc' }`, and the expected value for word.size(), example: 1.

Comment: Okay, I should have added the additional information you requested.

Comment: In this part of the json, the expected output is 1161192?

Comment: I'm using a dictionary of tagged words. So, each word has one or more 'tags' associated with it. There should be 1161192 words, each with 1 or more tags.

Comment: So in your example JSON, the response should be 6 words... I get it... I will test here.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't know how the number of words in the file can go from 1161192 in Python to 56057 in Java. I'm assuming that's what that means. I know that the Python dictionary has over a million words in it, thus a size of 1161192. The Java ObjectMapper only seems to hold 56057, which I'm assuming must be incorrect. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't Java. Everything is going fine. If you read your JSON on python:

```
with open('test.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
print len(data) #49815
```

Or if:

```
print len(wordcounts) #49815
```

The 1161192 is the number of tuples with word and tag. Example:

```
# wordcounts['drop'] has 3 tags.
print len(wordcounts['drop']) # 3
test = wordcounts['drop']
print test.N() # 59 ( "JJ": 1, "NN": 24, "VB": 34), 34+24+1
```

If you want Java shows the 1161192, you have to sum all tags:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
Map<String,Object> words = mapper.readValue(new File("test.json"), Map.class);
int value = 0;
for (String word : words.keySet()) {
    Map<String, Integer> tags = (Map) words.get(word);
    for (String tag : tags.keySet()) {
        value += tags.get(tag);
    }
}
System.out.println(value); #1161192
```